# Wysiwyg html editor for Java

Tags: java, spring, wysiwyg

Tell me please html editor with a file and image Manager adapted for Java. All that I find have connectors are written for PHP

Comment: I'm not able to understand your question properly.WYSIWYG editors are client side plugins right? What it has to do with Java?

Answer (score 0):

When I need something like that, generally I use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and I create a browser instance choosing Mozilla as rendering engine.

Then from the application is simple manipulate and interact with Mozilla and XPCOM api.

Hiere you can find a sample [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet260.java).